# FBX animation works in 3DSMax but not with Assimp

Tags: unity, 3d, 3dsmax, fbx, assimp

I have an FBX file that represent a **plane with an animation of the gear opening**. In my editor 3DSMax or in the Unity editor, the file and animation seem good, but when I use Open 3D Model(*the official viewer of Assimp*) or when I call the FBX file simply in an application, to see what the file will look like with the use of Assimp, I got some issues.

The object seems normal at the beginning, but when I try to launch the animation, **all my animated elements are going crazy**.

*Here's what it looks like* :

[image: Plane]

Here's my [FBX FILE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwVuF9QTPGaVMUdBbW52ZEpkcm8/view?usp=sharing)

Do you have experience something similar ? Does it come from my file or a parameter in Assimp ?

I am beginning to think that there is a problem with how Assimp handles pivot points, looks like objects are rotating using a different pivot point in Unity/open3mod.

Comment: Could you include some source of how you are utilizing AssImp?

Comment: The fact is I don't use it, I only use an application that uses it, I am beginning to think that there is a problem with how Assimp handles pivot points, looks like objects are rotating using a different pivot point in Unity/open3mod.

Comment: Then that application is not functioning how you expect, it's not an issue with AssImp; What exactly is your goal here? What do you want to happen and what can you change about the program you're using if it isn't your program?

Comment: My application is open3d, the official viewer of assimp. My goal is to use assimp in an application but it can't load my fbx properly, and I don't know if it comes from my file or from assimp.

Comment: It's most likely how Open3D is viewing such a complex model, you'll have to actually try to load your model with AssImp inside your application (the one you are building, not a model previewer) and come back here and ask a question with that specific implementation, your question isn't on topic here as there's no good answer to debugging the internals of a third party application.

Comment: Can you provide any further information about the model, how it is defined, how it is loaded, et cetera? Otherwise this is probably unanswerable here.

Comment: @MattJensJensen I also try to load it in my application and I have the same result.

Comment: I post a link to my FBX file

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I was attempting to make a model for a UAV in [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) and import it to [unreal engine](http://unrealengine.org). I think I recall as a solution I just redid my bone weights and it fixed the problem. Then i rotated the model to go the direction I wanted to in unreal.

Comment: Could you look at my file posted in my edit ? I don't think I have a bone weights problem.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you need to zero out any transforms before you export into an exchange format or else it's bound to go totally crazy on the other end.

That could be the issue.

It could also be a bug in the exporter or in how assimp reads it. File formats like FBX are very complicated and this is very common.

If you export the animation/skeleton separately it's also important that you export the exact same things (same selections) and make selections of nodes in the same way or it will also probably fail.

In short it could be many things and it is very hard to diagnose it exactly without sitting on your computer and/or looking at the file contents themselves.

Comment: I just posted my FBX if you want to take a look.